# Colocar un menú desplegable en una página sin que se oculte el menú

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

¿Cómo colocar un menú desplegable en una página principal y mandar llamar a las otras, pero sin que se oculte el menú?

Ya lo intenté con un `iframe` pero los submenús aparecen debajo del `iframe`:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <iframe src="menu.html"></iframe>
  </header>
</body>
```

También intenté con `z-index` pero no funcionó. ¿Existe alguna forma de hacerlo?

Nota - El menú esta hecho en CSS de la siguiente forma:

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#header {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li a {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  15px;
  display: block;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #434343;
}

.nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 140px;
}

.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

.nav li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav li ul li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav li ul li ul {
  right: -140px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="">inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">servicios</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">submenu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">submenu2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">submenu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">submenu2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Te planteas usar JavaScript? ¿O quieres mantener todo en HTML/CSS?

Comment: Hola Avaro Montoro, me gustaria mantener solo HTML y CSS, la verdad voy espesando a programar y no conosco Java, agradesco mucho tu ayuda.

Comment: Para mantener el menu abierto después de hacer click tengo una solución, pero no llego a comprender eso de llamar a otra página web. Además el CSS es limitado, se puede hacer magia hasta cierto punto

Comment: Si te refieres a que cuando le hagas click muestre debajo una página web. Por CSS es bastante complicado por no decir imposible ya que aun CSS no tiene selectores de padres por lo solo puedes ir hacia los hijos de los elementos

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, @matahombres, creo que no me explique bien, lo que necesito es tener un sitio con un menu desplegable, es decir si tengo 150 paginas y tengo el codigo independiente en cada una de ellas al agregar una nueva pagina tendria que modificar en cada una de las 150 paginas eso demoraria mucho tiempo innecesario, y creo que con un menu para todas seria mas facil, la pregunta es ¿como le hago para que ese menu unico aparesca en todas las paginas?

Comment: Prueba con frames https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.2.2.2

Comment: Lo que estás buscando requiere una estructura un poco "avanzada" por así decirlo... mira esto: [AdminLTE](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html), creo que se aproxima a lo que planteas.